# Get value from protected member of class

Tags: arduino-mega, class, functions

i'm really new to Arduino.
I have Arduino Mega, a USB host shield and a barcode scanner. I'm using this library >> [link](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) and modified it example so barcode scanner worked (Got it from [here](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/issues/323)) to read what barcode scanner scanned and it worked just fine.

```
#include <usbhid.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#include <hiduniversal.h>
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <SPI.h>

class MyParser : public HIDReportParser {
  public:
    MyParser();
    void Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf);
    uint8_t getValue();
  protected:
    uint8_t KeyToAscii(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnScanFinished();
};

MyParser::MyParser() {}

void MyParser::Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf) {
  // If error or empty, return
  if (buf[2] == 1 || buf[2] == 0) return;

  for (uint8_t i = 7; i >= 2; i--) {
    // If empty, skip
    if (buf[i] == 0) continue;

    // If enter signal emitted, scan finished
    if (buf[i] == UHS_HID_BOOT_KEY_ENTER) {
      OnScanFinished();
    }

    // If not, continue normally
    else {
      // If bit position not in 2, it's uppercase words
      OnKeyScanned(i > 2, buf, buf[i]);
    }

    return;
  }
}

uint8_t MyParser::getValue() {
  uint8_t getAscii;
  bool upper; uint8_t mod; uint8_t key;
  getAscii = KeyToAscii(upper, mod, key);
  return getAscii;
}

uint8_t MyParser::KeyToAscii(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  // Letters
  if (VALUE_WITHIN(key, 0x04, 0x1d)) {
    if (upper) return (key - 4 + 'A');
    else return (key - 4 + 'a');
  }

  // Numbers
  else if (VALUE_WITHIN(key, 0x1e, 0x27)) {
    return ((key == UHS_HID_BOOT_KEY_ZERO) ? '0' : key - 0x1e + '1');
  }

  return 0;
}

void MyParser::OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  uint8_t ascii = KeyToAscii(upper, mod, key);
  Serial.print((char)ascii);
}

void MyParser::OnScanFinished() {
  Serial.println(" - Finished");
}

USB          Usb;
USBHub       Hub(&Usb);
HIDUniversal Hid(&Usb);
MyParser     Parser;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
  Serial.println("Start");

  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.println("OSC did not start.");
  }

  delay( 200 );

  Hid.SetReportParser(0, &Parser);
}

void loop() {
  Usb.Task();
}
```

So, I want to get the value from `(char)ascii`, store to `char` on `loop` and run it.

```
void MyParser::OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  uint8_t ascii = KeyToAscii(upper, mod, key);
  Serial.print((char)ascii);
}
```

I tried created function that return the value but still no luck.

```
uint8_t MyParser::getValue() {
  uint8_t getAscii;
  bool upper; uint8_t mod; uint8_t key;
  getAscii = KeyToAscii(upper, mod, key);
  return getAscii;
}
```

Called it on loop:

```
void loop() {
  Usb.Task();
  uint8_t abcd = Parser.getValue();
  char c = (char)abcd;
  Serial.print(c);
}
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Upper mod and key have no defined value in getValue.

Comment: I don't understamd, what the problem is or what you are trying to achieve. Is your KeyToAscii function not working properly? If so, how is it not working?